# To use auto-increment in MySQL or not?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have read certain places that it is a good practice to typically use an auto-incrementing Primary key for most MySQL tables, rather than simply relying on a non-increment field that will be enforced to be unique.

My question is specifically about a User table, and a table connected to it by a Foreign Key. Here's the schema:

```
TABLE Users {
    id
    name
    ...
}

TABLE Authors {
    user_id (FK)
    author_bio
}
```

Should the Authors table have its own auto-incrementing primary key as well, or should it rely on the user_id foreign key as a primary key?

**ALSO**

Are there noticeable performance reasons to NOT use the auto-incrementing id as the Primary?

Comment: Using the primary key of the `USERS` table as the primary key of the `AUTHORS` table suggests a 1:1 relationship.  Normalization (3NF?) dictates there shouldn't be two tables in that situation.  Adding a separate primary key (autoincrement or not) doesn't change that...

Comment: OMG - a user MIGHT be an author, but an author WILL be a user. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, if there's only ever one USER related to a single AUTHOR record -- that is 1:1.  The decision depends on your business rules, but authors have been known to have pseudonyms (aliases) - IE: Steven King wrote as Richard Bachman

Comment: OMG, I think putting everything in one table would be fairly inefficient, though. In my case, maybe 1 out of every 100 accounts will be an author. Which would mean that there would be a lot of empty fields in the User table without separation...right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not either-or.  If you use an auto increment primary key, and you have candidate keys that need to enforce constraints, then your schema should have both.

Both your `user` and `author` tables should have individual primary keys. (Every table must have a primary key.)  I would not use the foreign key as the primary key.  If that truly is the case, I wouldn't have a separate author table; I'd put those columns in the user table.

PS - My naming preference is singular for tables.  It should be `user` and `author` tables.  They happen to contain multiple rows, but a single row means a single entity.

Comment: So you are saying it's cool to have an auto-incrementing primary, and then the foreign, even though the foreign is unique and could (technically) be used as a primary? There is something about the consistency of each table having an auto incrementing key that i like.

Comment: Duffy, thanks for elaborating...I'm thinking that I agree with your thoughts...something feels cleaner know each table will have a common thread of primary key type

Answer (score 1):

You most definitely want the `Authors` table to have its own primary key such as `authors_id`, and then have `user_id` as a foreign key.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why, so I can get the gist of it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If every author maps to exactly one user (and you're sure this isn't going to change), you can get away with having `user_id` as a primary key. If not, you'll need an independent primary key for `Authors`.

(Note that the reverse relation doesn't have to be true: not every user has to map to an author.)